# use jq to format json data into csv data

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

```
{
    "Users": [
        {
            "Attributes": [
                {
                    "Name": "sub",
                    "Value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "phone_number",
                    "Value": "1234"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "referral_code",
                    "Value": "abc"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Attributes": [
                {
                    "Name": "sub",
                    "Value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "phone_number",
                    "Value": "5678"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "referral_code",
                    "Value": "def"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I produce output like below ?

1,1234,abc

2,5678,def

```
jq '.Users[] .Attributes[] .Value' test.json

produces


1
1234
abc
2
5678
def
```

Comment: I did not downvote but am fairly sure the main reason is that you did not show any "research effort", e.g. a failed attempt.  (See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) Also, you did not specify whether the ordering of the Name values within Attributes is guaranteed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is the cleanest way to handle this, but the following will get the desired output:

```
.Users[].Attributes | map(.Value) | @csv
```

1. Loop through all the deep Attributes `.Users[].Attributes`
2. [`map()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example21) to get all the `Value`'s
3. Convert to `@csv`

#### [jqPlay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Y3mTqmOHC7)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the output to be guaranteed to be CSV, and if you're sure the "Name" values are presented in the same order, you could go with:

```
.Users[].Attributes
| from_entries
| [.[]]
| join(",")
```

To be safe though it would be better to ensure consistency of ordering:

```
(.Users[0] | [.Attributes[] | .Name]) as $keys
| .Users[]
| .Attributes
| from_entries
| [.[ $keys[] ]]
| join(",")
```

Using `join(",")` will produce the comma-separated values as shown in the Q (without the quotation marks), but is not **guaranteed** to produce the expected CSV for all valid values of the input.  If you don't mind the pesky quotation marks, you could use `@csv`, or if you want to skip the quotation marks around all numeric values:

```
map(tonumber? // .) | @csv
```

Comment: I'd upvote for the consistent ordering alternative, except you don't produce CSV as requested.

Comment: @ikegami - I used join(",") precisely to conform with the request, but have updated the A to give more details and options.